# Set sender name in JavaMailSender

Tags: java, spring, email

I'm using JavaMailSender to send an email to my client by my gmail account.
In my gmail account settings, I can set value to "Send mail as" in order to display my customize name in my client email.
For example, if I send email in gmail, my client email will show this:

> From: This is my customize name (not my email address)
>
> To: client-email@mail.com
>
> Subject ...
>
> Body ...

How can I set up the configuration of JavaMailSender in Spring ?

This is my configuration file:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
  <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="myemailaddress@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="mypassword@gmail.com" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
       <props>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
           </props>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `MimeMessageHelper` as suggested by mumbasa. You can configure it like

```
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
message.setTo(...);
message.setFrom("Your Site <info@your-site.com>");
message.setSubject(...);
```

Note how `message.setFrom(String from)` is actually being set. Instead of setting the from address to something like:

`info@your-site.com`

Set it to

`Your Site <info@your-site.com>`

Comment: is the closing > missing by intention?

Comment: Good catch. This has ben fixed.

Comment: Not to be picky, I'm coming from 4 hrs lost due to a missing slash in some other code... :-)

Answer (score 1):

To show email with a customized name showing in the inbox. I use MimeMessageHelper class from method. The one requiring two String parameters. It takes the email address and the customized name in this order

Comment: Always show example code please. Remember that future visitors will also benefit from your answers. And sometimes answers such as these lose relevancy without samples.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the **SimpleMailMessage** class (org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage)
you can do :

```
simpleMailMessage.setFrom("email@mail.com");
```